# Jquery conflict between two codes drives me crazy

Tags: jquery

I believe there is an conflict between those two Jqueries. My Jquery version is: 1.8.2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    var portfolioCarousel = $("#widget-portfolio-2");

    portfolioCarousel.carouFredSel({
        width : "100%",
        height : "auto",
        circular : false,
        responsive : true,
        infinite : false,
        auto : false,
        items : {
            width : 280,
            visible: {
                max: 1
            }
        },
        scroll : {
            wipe : true
        },
        prev : {    
            button : "#widget-portfolio-2-prev",
            key : "left"
        },
        next : { 
            button : "#widget-portfolio-2-next",
            key : "right"
        },
        onCreate : function () {
            $(window).on('resize', function(){
                portfolioCarousel.parent().add(portfolioCarousel).css('height', portfolioCarousel.children().first().outerHeight() + 'px');
            }).trigger('resize');
        }
    });

});
```

and this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#example2').showbizpro({
                    dragAndScroll:"off",
                    visibleElementsArray:[5,4,3,1],
                    carousel:"on",
                    heightOffsetBottom:10,
                    mediaMaxHeight:[150,150,150,150],
                    rewindFromEnd:"off",
                    autoPlay:"off",
                    delay:2000,
                    speed:750
                });



                // THE FANCYBOX PLUGIN INITALISATION
                jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();





            });

        </script>
```

The second one works perfect. The first one doesn't.

I hope someone solves this issue.

Can you see the problem?
Thank you in advance,

Cruxy

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

above first script and try...

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Remove all script errors from the file:

if you dont want to use fancybox, remove it from script..

Comment: 1 message is hidden by filters. Show all messages.
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' kledingpakket.php:1030
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught ReferenceError: siblingsFader is not defined

Comment: add the script that needed for running fancybox in the page

Comment: I change the Jquey version to 1.8.2 because I go some issues with other codes.

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this if you are using jquery 1.10.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {


var portfolioCarousel = $("#widget-portfolio-2");

portfolioCarousel.carouFredSel({
    width : "100%",
    height : "auto",
    circular : false,
    responsive : true,
    infinite : false,
    auto : false,
    items : {
        width : 280,
        visible: {
            max: 1
        }
    },
    scroll : {
        wipe : true
    },
    prev : {    
        button : "#widget-portfolio-2-prev",
        key : "left"
    },
    next : { 
        button : "#widget-portfolio-2-next",
        key : "right"
    },
    onCreate : function () {
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            portfolioCarousel.parent().add(portfolioCarousel).css('height', portfolioCarousel.children().first().outerHeight() + 'px');
        }).trigger('resize');
    }
});

$('#example2').showbizpro({
    dragAndScroll:"off",
    visibleElementsArray:[5,4,3,1],
    carousel:"on",
    heightOffsetBottom:10,
    mediaMaxHeight:[150,150,150,150],
    rewindFromEnd:"off",
    autoPlay:"off",
    delay:2000,
    speed:750
   });



 // THE FANCYBOX PLUGIN INITALISATION
 $(".fancybox").fancybox();

});
</script>
```